# Javascript: regexp to remove .html

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am searching for some regexp which remove the .html extension of a string.

I already found these two for some reason they don't work:

```
var path = './views/contacts/node/item.html';
var otherPath = path;
path.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '');
console.log(path);
// returns ./views/contacts/node/item.html
otherPath.replace(/(.*)\.[^.]+$/, '');
console.log(otherPath);
// also returns ./views/contacts/node/item.html
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original `regex` works, you just weren't capturing the return result. Both of the folowing will work:

```
path = path.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '');

path = path.replace(/\.html$/, '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AE2BY/

Comment: Perhaps you could also elaborate on what the original regex's were trying to do and why they weren't working?

Comment: I’d change that to `/\.html$/` to make sure it only captures extensions, but it’s the right method.

Comment: they should remove the file extensions

Answer (score 1):

```
path = path.replace(/\.html$/, '');
```

Assuming the .html extension is at the end of the string, always.

As for what's wrong with the regexes you mention -- they're incorrect and would never match the sample string you gave.

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = './views/contacts/node/item.html';
var otherPath = path.replace(/(\.html).*?$/, '');

console.log(otherPath) // './views/contacts/node/item'
```

This should remove everything after and including "`.html`".

The reason why you weren't getting what you wanted from the functions you listed above is because you were `console.log`'ing the wrong variable. Change:

```
var path = './views/contacts/node/item.html';
var otherPath = path;
path.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '');
console.log(path);
```

To:

```
var path = './views/contacts/node/item.html';
var otherPath = path.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '');
console.log(otherPath);
```